Flutter app crashing when iOS dictation keyboard used after using camera
I have a Flutter app where when I try to access the speech dictation feature on iOS keyboard, it crashes the app.
Image
I am using the camera plugin from pub.dev and speech dictation is the native iOS keyboard as seen in the picture. Presently on latest version of Flutter(3.22.1).
I get this error on XCode

"Application violated contract by causing UIApplicationMain() to return. This incident will be reported."

I believe this is related to the Audio permissions being blocked by the iOS itself. I have even added permissions in the iOS app in Info.plist for
        <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Speech recognition is used to dictate text in the app</string>
    <key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Speech recognition is used to dictate text in the app</string>

and
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 10.0
           config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
         end
         config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
  
      
        # dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
  
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',
  
        # dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
  
        # dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
      ]
      end
  end
end

in the Podfile and run pod install still the app crashes. I am not sure what else can fix the crash?
